# Running Access from Command line but not loading it?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I would like to launch a MS Access macro from the command line (it's being run from another tool) to generate an output.  Thing is, I'd prefer it if it could supress access from loading it's interface.  I just want it to run the macro and shut down.  Any thoughts on how to do this?

I've used a command line something like this so far:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS" "S:\filepath\Database\database.accdb" /x Macro1
```

Comment: Please explain what suppress Access from loading its interface means.

Comment: Sure!  Basically I just want it to do it's thing but seemingly invisible.  No windows pop up.  Just execute the macro and close once done.

Comment: Thanks.  To me, that sounds like just hide the Access application window.  I don't know anything about that other tool you mentioned.  Can it run VBA code or shell out to a VBScript?

Comment: Well it's not 100% important what the other tool is.  It's actually "R".  I'm using it to execute a system command line (ie same thing you would enter into CMD).  Access will then export one of it's tables into CSV, where R will then pick up the CSV.

Comment: So then can you call a command line like `cscript.exe NewVBScriptFile.vbs`?

Comment: PS. I'm well aware that R can just do an ODBC to Access, however unfortunately my access is 32bit and I need to run R in 64bit which, apparently even in 2015, is impossible.. so this is a workaround :)

Comment: Yes, something like that.  I just don't want an access window to pop up, I just want it to do it's work and exit, unbeknownst to the user.

Comment: Well the ODBC thing is irrelevant.  You can't run an Access macro from an ODBC connection under any circumstance.  A macro can only be run from within an Access application session.

Comment: You misunderstand--if I could ODBC I would just ODBC direct to the table, instead of have this workaround use the macro to export the table to a CSV

Comment: You're right, I did misunderstand.  With the 64 bit Access ACE driver, you can create an ODBC connection from a 64 bit process to an Access db.  Have you investigated that option?

Comment: Wouldn't both programs need to be running in 64 bit?  I only have access 32 bit and no option to get 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use COM automation from VBScript to create an Access application instance, hide it from view, run your macro, and then shut down Access.

I saved the following script as *RunAccessMacro.vbs* and ran it in a command prompt window using this as the command line ...

```
cscript //NoLogo C:\share\vbscript\RunAccessMacro.vbs
```

This is *RunAccessMacro.vbs* ...

```vb
Option Explicit

Const cstrDbFile = "C:\share\Access\database1.mdb"
Dim accessApp

Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.Visible = False
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase cstrDbFile, False ' open shared
accessApp.DoCmd.RunMacro "Macro1"
accessApp.Quit
Set accessApp = Nothing
```